# Postman Collection to run multiple times - possible to send random unique ID in json body?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I would like to measure the POST and GET endpoint performance by using POSTMAN collection - run feature.

ideally, i wanted to use same POST endpoint, but the json data is different at each iteration.

Possible to do that in POSTMAN?

Comment: yes it is possible to run a collection multiple times with a data file (csv/json)

Comment: @JeevananthanKesavan thank, i will do research on data file. i just try to run collection, with one GET endpoint 1 iteration but response is 404 in collection runner, it is response 200 when i run the endpoint individually. anyidea whats wrong in runner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the postman api you can write [scripted tests](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/intro-to-scripts/) where you can change the data between each test. It can be the same request with different data.

Also you can use dynamic variables in the [sandbox](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/)

I hope this helps

Comment: i have read the sanbox refrence, not sure which one to use, example json body { "testitem": "bag",  "testID": "123"} , i want the "testID" using random ID, how can i do it in the POSTMAN 'test' tab?